# SQlite result undefined issue in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm having a problem with seemingly textbook example of SQlite usage:

Code below

```js
const db_client = new sqlite3.Database(HISTORY_DB, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message, '## ERROR ##');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to the SQlite DB');
});

const current_hour = new Date().getHours();
const sql = `SELECT value FROM history where hour = ${current_hour}`;

const getSql = async (sql) => {
  await db_client.get(sql, [], (err, row) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
  } 
    console.log(row.value, 'FIRST');
    return parseInt(row.value);
  })
};
console.log(await getSql(sql), 'SECOND');
```

For some reason I cannot get the value of the sql response. I've tried a couple of approaches and its always undefined, but console.log works. I cannot figure it out.

Console log pasted below:

```
undefined SECOND
Connected to the SQlite DB
287439002531265 FIRST
```

Comment: You cant return a value from inside a callback, you need to return a `Promise` from `getSql` and resolve it from within callback instead.

Comment: Well, what is 'SECOND' used for? are you trying to log it to the console?
If so change the line to this. console.log(await getSql(sql) + 'SECOND');

Comment: hey @James thanks for suggestion, it has not crossed my mind to do it.